# Filtering data before populating view from FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Taking reference from FireChat app I used FirebaseRecyclerAdapter in my app, it is working fine but I need to filter data which equals to specific user ID.

In populateView if I does that data is getting filtered but a blank recycler Item item is also getting created.

```
mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Tags, TagsViewHolder>(
            Tags.class,
            R.layout.item_message,
            TagsViewHolder.class,
            mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("tags")) {

        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(TagsViewHolder viewHolder, Tags tags, int position) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
            if((tags.getUserid()).equals(mFirebaseUser.getUid()))
            viewHolder.tagTextView.setText(tags.getTagname());
        }
    };
```

**Is there any way I can filter it before a view gets created?**

my POJO class is:

```
    public class Tags {
    private String userid;
    private String tagname;
    private HashMap<String, Object> timestampCreated;

    public Tags() {
    }

    public Tags(String userid, String tagname, HashMap<String, Object> timestampCreated) {
        this.userid = userid;
        this.tagname = tagname;
        this.timestampCreated = timestampCreated;
    }

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public String getTagname() {
        return tagname;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Object> getTimestampCreated() {
        return timestampCreated;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Client-side filtering is an open feature request for FirebaseUI. See https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/15.

Client-side filtering of data, means that the app first download data and then doesn't show it to the user. This is wasteful and most users of mobile apps will appreciate it if your app only downloads data that it shows to them.

The best ways to deal with displaying a subset of the data is to either model the data in a way so that you can directly access the subset of data that you want to display, or to use [Firebase queries to limit the data that is retrieved](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/retrieve-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: Okay @Frank thanks, I get it. If i don't want to use Firebase query then can you give an idea how to do it with modeling data?

Comment: In this case you could model the messages per user. So `/messagesPerUser/$uid/$messageId`.

Comment: Yeah I got what I was looking for, I just implemented what you suggested.It works as expected, Thanks a lot @Frank.

Comment: What if I have a car database and I want to get all the cars with a color *similar* to a given HEX code? i.e: All the red cars sorted by the closest color to "#ab1100". How can I achieve this using FireBase?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I need to filter data based on the string value (String.startsWith(prefix)) but I think Firebase API does not support that. What is my best bet here to fetch only relevant data from server?

Comment: Firebase supports filtering the range of data that is returned. Have a look at this documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data. If you're having problems making it work, post a question with the [minimum code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This reply does not address the question, in my case I just want to filter out one record in what could be 100s