# RecyclerView + FirebaseRecyclerAdapter + Spinner Filter in activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have a recyclerview with **FirebaseRecyclerAdapter** and a spinner.

It show in activity a list of objects retrieve of firabase database.
My question is: **Which better way for using filters in recycler view when user select a value in spinner**? **When selected a value in spinner below, nothing happens... Not update RecyclerView**

**exemple**: When user select 'Brazil' in **spinner**, call a existent query like
*`query =  databaseReference.child("People").orderByChild("country").equalTo("Brazil").getRef()`;* //I still dont know if this working.

```
    query =  databaseReference.child("People").getRef();
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    spinnerFilter = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinFilter);
```

> //--SPINNER EVENT SELECT--

```
AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener selectedListener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> spinner, View container, int position, long id)
            {
                if(id == 0)
                {
                    query =  databaseReference.child("PeopleList").orderByChild("country").equalTo("Canada").getRef();
                }else
                if(id == 1)
                {
                    query =  databaseReference.child("PeopleList").orderByChild("country").equalTo("Brazil").getRef();
                }else
                if(id == 2)
                {
                    query =  databaseReference.child("PeopleList").orderByChild("country").equalTo("EUA").getRef();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                query =  databaseReference.child("PeopleList").getRef();
            }
        }; 
          spinnerFilter.setOnItemSelectedListener(selectedListener);
```

> //---RECYCLER VIEW----

```
    if (mRecyclerView != null) {
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    }
    gLayoutManager= new GridLayoutManager(this, 2);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gLayoutManager);
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<People, PeopleListViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<People, PeopleListViewHolder>
            (
                    People.class,
                    R.layout.layout_people_item,
                    PeopleListViewHolder.class,
                    query
            )
    {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(PeopleListViewHolder viewHolder, People model, int position)
        {
            viewHolder.tvName.setText(model.getName());
    Picasso.with(PeopleListActivity.this).load(model.getUrlThumbnail()).into(viewHolder.thumbnail);

        }
    };
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I check a lot links here but none success:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39076702/filtering-data-before-populating-view-from-firebaserecycleradapter?rq=1
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/15
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/O1kJ4VLUg10
https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/15
```

Thanks very much if can help me.
[image]

Comment: What do you want to ask actually?

Comment: Which better way for using filters in recycler view when user select a value in spinner? When selected a value in spinner above, nothing happens... Not update RecyclerView.

Comment: When the user selects an item in the spinner, you create a new `query`. That part seems correct. You'll then need to create a new `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` with that new query and attach it to the existing `RecyclerView`.

Comment: hmm.. Very thanks Frank, I read all sugestions that you give and links below. I was think that can to enjoy existent recyclerview or some filtering method of firebase. Go try now your suggest.